# Why can't I add sky nodes to a lamp in Blender Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, node-editor, light

[image]

I feel like my interface is missing the ability to add sky.

Although I have easily applied sky in another file before, no matter what I do in this file, the sky is black.

What went wrong?

Comment: The 'sky' is defined in the world : the little button next to the object (yellow cube and which look like... a world) of your screen capture. Here you are showing the object material nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant add sky nodes to a lamp, you have to create a new World "material" and add nodes to it's setup, not the Sun lamp.

In the *Properties Window* go to the world tab (Fourth tab with a blue globe) and add a new one there if there isn't one already.

Then in the *Node editor Window* switch to *World* node type in bottom header, second button with the same blue globe icon.